# How do i return a node to its original position after a rotation transition

Tags: java, animation, javafx, rotation

I have a Applied a on mouse entered action listener and a on mouse exited listener to a button.when the mouse hovers over  the button, it rotates and on exit its suppose to stop and return to its original position but unfortunately i don't know how to achieve this....any ideas? Here is what i have.

```
 finishButton.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
        buttonRotateAnimation(finishButton);
        play();
    });

    finishButton.setOnMouseExited(event ->{

        stop();


    });
```

created methods

```
public RotateTransition buttonRotateAnimation(Button button){
    rotateTransition = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(2),button);
    rotateTransition.setFromAngle(0);
    rotateTransition.setToAngle(720);
    rotateTransition.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    rotateTransition.setAutoReverse(true);

    return rotateTransition;
}

public void play() {
    rotateTransition.play();
}


public void stop() {
    rotateTransition.stop();
}
```

Comment: Try adding this to your stop() method: rotationTransition.getNode().setAngle(0);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a ChangeListener to the statusProperty and when the status is Status.STOPPED you simply add another RotateTransition like this:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            StackPane root = new StackPane();

            Button button = new Button( "I'm rotating!");

            RotateTransition rotateTransition = createRotateTransition(button);

            button.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, e -> {
                rotateTransition.play();
            });

            button.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, e -> {
                rotateTransition.stop();
            });

            root.getChildren().add( button);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public RotateTransition createRotateTransition(Button button){

        RotateTransition rotateTransition = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(2),button);

        rotateTransition.setFromAngle(0);
        rotateTransition.setToAngle(720);
        rotateTransition.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        rotateTransition.setAutoReverse(true);

        rotateTransition.statusProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Status>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Status> observable, Status oldValue, Status newValue) {

                if( newValue == Status.STOPPED) {

                    RotateTransition transition = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(2),button);

                    transition.setFromAngle(button.getRotate());
                    transition.setToAngle(0);
                    transition.setCycleCount(1);
                    transition.setAutoReverse(true);
                    transition.play();

                }

            }

        });
        return rotateTransition;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```